# Page and images load very slow when launching the site

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small gallery site with 65 images. I created a simple html page with a slide show. The site loads pretty slow. also, the images load very slow when trying to access it. What do you recommend?

Here is how I load my images.

```
<p>
    <a href="javascript:void(viewer.show(0))" alt="Launch slideshow" class="m-btn">Launch Slideshow</a>
</p>
<p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var img;                    
        var images = []; // created from loop
        var viewer = new PhotoViewer();
        for(var j = 1; j < 69; j++){
            var fullImg = '/image_'+ ("000" + j).slice(-3) +'.JPG';
            viewer.add('photos/image_' + ("000" + j).slice(-3) + '.JPG');   
            images.push(fullImg);                   
        }
        var mastercontainer=document.createElement("div");
        mastercontainer.setAttribute('class','mastercontainer');


        var main=document.createElement("div");
        main.setAttribute('class','main');


        var slidesDiv=document.createElement("div");
        slidesDiv.setAttribute('class','slideshow');

        document.body.appendChild(mastercontainer); 
        document.body.appendChild(main);                
        document.body.appendChild(slidesDiv);

        for (var i in images) {
            var num = parseInt(i);
            var img=document.createElement("img");
            img.setAttribute('src', 'photos/thumbnail'+images[num]);
            img.setAttribute('width', 200);
            img.setAttribute('height', 200);
            img.setAttribute('style', 'margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:0px;border:1px solid #000000;border-radius: 10px;');
            var link=document.createElement("a");
            link.setAttribute('href', 'photos'+images[i]);
            link.setAttribute('onClick','return viewer.show('+i+')');
            slidesDiv.appendChild(link);
            link.appendChild(img);
        }
    </script>
    <br/>
</p>
```

Comment: Um, do not load 65 images....Load what is needed to start and lazy load the rest.

Comment: I agree. Loading 65 images can be a huge resource drain. Why not paginate and show 5 at a time? Or only load when the user scrolls to that image in a list?

Comment: If you need to parallelize, you could always use a CDN and some trickery to allow the browser to open multiple HTTP requests.

Comment: Thank you I will try the lazy load plugin and update you as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better responsiveness you may want to try to load the html and lazy load the images for the slideshow as they are needed. i.e on the slideshow's `slide` or `change` event for example.

Unless you're rolling out your own slideshow module, most slideshow plugins have this feature built in.

There is a great jquery plugin to lazyload images available for you to use

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: Thank you I worked it out with lazyload and also I optimized the images for the web. They were way to large.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to look the network tab in Chrome/Firefox developer console, i think images are loaded synchronously and they probably are too large so they slowly load.

Answer (score 1):

Is the speed in the Javascript execution or in the image load? 65 images can be pretty intensive, especially if they are large images coming over the network. checking your Chrome tools can provide insight into this. You could try loading the same, small image 65 times to see if the JS is the culprit, but my gut reaction is that the image loading is the bottle neck. In that case, you could try some server-side compression using something like imagemagick or GD. Generally, I resize images into a few standard sizes on upload, but that may not always be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try lazyloading. Look here for a jQuery Plugin:  http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload